# Select last registred user from database

Tags: php, database

I have a problem trying to select the last registered user.  I'm trying to print newly registered users to the screen - can anyone help?

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST['registrovat']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passwordre = $_POST['passwordrepeat'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if ($password == $passwordre)
    {
        if ($username && $email)
        {
            $password = md5(sha1(md5($password)));

            $db_servername = "localhost";
            $db_username = "kubaaivcaweb";
            $db_name = "insanity";
            $db_password = "XXXXX";
            $username = $_POST['username'];

            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $db_conn = mysqli_connect($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conn, "INSERT INTO `8` SET username='$username', password='$password', ip='$ip', email='$email'");

            echo "Registrace proběhla úspěšně";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Hesla se neshodují!";
    }
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($new))
{
    $new = mysqli_query($db_conn, "SELECT * FROM `8` ORDER BY `id` DESC");

    echo "<p>Nejnovější uživatel:" . $row['username'] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: your table name is 8?

Comment: yes i want to rename it but...

Comment: `md5(sha1(md5($password)))` is not a safe way to hash passwords. Using `$_POST` values without sanitizing them is also not safe. Your while loop also makes no sense.

Comment: Also no need of quotes at the time of writing the table name and chane it

Comment: Okey thanks, but this is not the main problem. i have problem with last php code

Comment: @JakubStanek You are using `$new` before is has been created. Put the query outside the loop. You should also check for errors. All programmers make mistakes, even the best.

Comment: oh i dont know the loop did my friend i dont understand it well...

Comment: I remember those loops, they were "special" to read through results of a query, after `mysql_fetch_array();` old though.

Comment: Your logic has you connecting to the database only if multiple conditions are true. But then you assume it is open in your last few lines. Check the return value of mysqli_query and display the error if it returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put your query inside instead of outside your loop. Your code looks like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($new)) {
    $new = mysqli_query($db_conn, "SELECT * FROM `8` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    echo "<p>Nejnovější uživatel:" . $row['username'] . "</p>";
}
```

Instead it should look like this:

```
echo "DEBUG before query<br  />"
if (! $new = mysqli_query($db_conn, "SELECT * FROM `8` ORDER BY `id` DESC")) {
    echo "DB error: ". mysqli_error($db_conn). "<br />" ;
    exit 1;
}
echo "DEBUG after query<br  />"
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($new))  {
    echo "<p>Nejnovější uživatel:" . $row['username'] . "</p>"; 
}
echo "DEBUG after fetch<br  />"
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Did you put the error message `echo` in? What output did you get?

Comment: Try with the new debug statements I added. I am starting to think you are loading the wrong page or have caching issues or something.

Comment: Can you confirm (via phpmyadmin or the like) that you actually have rows in the 8 table?

Comment: It works now.. im sorry it was my bad... look where i have $db_conn:D

Comment: Are you talking about where $db_conn was initialized? Like in my last comment up above? :-)